# Division error getting token value with too many decimals

Tags: tokens, erc-20, price, math

I am using the method below to get the value of a token, it works very well when the token value is not something very low like $0.000004101, the problem is in the division of the wBNB / TOKEN reserve, see the code:

```
        token = web3.toChecksumAddress(token_to_buy)
        sellTokenContract = web3.eth.contract(token, abi=sellAbi)
        symbol = sellTokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
        decimals = sellTokenContract.functions.decimals().call()
        pairAddress = uniswap_contract.functions.getPair(token, WBNB).call()
        pairContract = web3.eth.contract(address=pairAddress, abi=ABI)
        reserves = pairContract.functions.getReserves().call()
        xtoken = reserves[0] / math.pow(10, decimals)
        xbnb = reserves[1] / math.pow(10, 18)
        time = reserves[2]
        valtoken = xbnb / xtoken
        valbnb = xtoken / xbnb
```

a token contract example: 0x54626300818e5c5b44db0fcf45ba4943ca89a9e2

The error occurs on this line:

```
valtoken = xbnb / xtoken
```

where xbnb value = **445.650555569178884** and xtoken value = **40592474978.52064**

445.650555569178884 / 40592474978.52064 = 1.0978649513921072**e-08**

I think the problem is in the division, because with most tokens it works, so how can I do this kind of division in python, or am I wrong in something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the value `$0.000004101`? The only difference between your computation and the router one is that the router takes out the 0.25% fee.

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity, the concept of floating-point numbers doesn't exist and what is known as "token decimals" is simply a work around the fact that Solidity only deals with numbers in integer formats. I think the issue in your code above is when the divisor is greater than the dividend, resulting in a value that truncates to `0`.

I would suggest for you to use a Solidity math library to make your life easier, and for which I would recommend [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math).

Comment: I'm using web3py with python, I looked at the library and it's SOL with SDK in JS, is there any similar lib in python?

Comment: Well, the decimals and truncation are mainly a Solidity issue. If you're building a Python scripts with web3py, you could easily convert number formats through the utilities available for you.